# How to use PostMessage in a React Native webview?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-web, react-native-webview

I'm trying to use the postmessage to a page opened in a webview inside a React Native App. I tried many times, but still wasn't able to send it.

I can listen to messages from the webpage normally. I just can't send anything back.

I'm currently using `react-native-webview 11.6.5`

```
export default function WebPage() {
  const webviewRef = useRef();

  const onMessage = (event) => {
    //receive message from the web page. working here until here
    const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);

    //reply the message
    webviewRef.current.postMessage(
      JSON.stringify({reply: 'reply'}),
      '*'
    )
  }

  return <View>
    <WebView
      ref={webviewRef}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={{ uri: 'https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html' }}
      domStorageEnabled
      javaScriptEnabled
      onMessage={onMessage}
    />
  </View>


}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Ahmed Gaber help I was able to find this issue https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/809 and discover they're changing `postMessage` to `injectJavaScript`.

So I updated my code `onMessage` to the following:

```
const onMessage = (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);

  //reply the message
  webviewRef.current.injectJavaScript(
    `window.postMessage(
      {
        reply: 'reply'
      }
    );`
  )
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To send data from app to `webview`, use [injectedJavaScript](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript)
To send data from `webview` to app, use [postMessage](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#postmessagestr)
To receive data in `webview` sent by `postMessage`, use [onMessage](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onmessage)

```js
// This Js function will be injected into the web page after the document finishes loading.
// This function will Post a message to WebView.
const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({key : "value"}));
})();`;



<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev' }}
  injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
  onMessage={(event) => {
       const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
       alert(data.key);
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: hm... thank you so much for your help. Thanks to help I found out they're changing "postMessage" to "injectJavascript" and was able to solve it using `webviewRef.current.injectJavaScript(INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT)`

Comment: There's a [guide "Communicating between JS and Native" that explains it all](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native) now.

Answer (score 6):

React native code

```
    function getInjectableJSMessage(message) {
        return `
          (function() {
            document.dispatchEvent(new MessageEvent('message', {
              data: ${JSON.stringify(message)}
            }));
          })();
        `;
      }
function sendDataToWebView() {
    webviewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(
      getInjectableJSMessage("Hello")
    );
  }
```

React web app code

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleEvent(message) {
      console.log(message.data);
    }
    document.addEventListener("message", handleEvent);

    return () =>
      document.removeEventListener("message", handleEvent);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How do I give an answer 100 upvotes? because this really saved me a lot of time. Thank you